# Django - uploading static image as default ImageField file

Tags: django, django-models, django-file-upload

This is my models.py:

```
def get_profileImage_file_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('%s/uploadedPhotos/profileImages' % instance.user_id, filename)

class UserExtended(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    profileImage = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_profileImage_file_path, default='/static/images/myProfileIcon.png')
```

Now, I want the default image (which is in my static folder) to save to the path given in the

```
get_profileImage_file_path
```

function. In my settings.py, I have defined media_root and media_URL as:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/username/Documents/aSa/userPhotos'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

For some reason, when I pass the user object in the template and in the template, if I do:

```
<img class='profilePic' src="{{ user.userextended.profileImage.url }}" height='120px' alt="" />
```

No image shows up and when I open up the 'inspect element' section in chrome, it gives a 404 error saying:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/username/Documents/djcode/aS/aSa/static/images/myProfileIcon.png 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

even though that is the correct file path to the image. (I'm also not sure why it's giving the entire file path, isn't it just supposed to start from /static/? Even when I 'view source', the entire url is there.) How do I make it so that the default image which is located in the static folder uploads to the path provided in the

```
get_profileImage_file_path
```

function?

Comment: Did you work this one out?

Answer (score 1):

In general we use the config as follows for media :

```
BASE_DIR = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))

MEDIA_ROOT_DIR = 'media'
MEDIA_ROOT = normpath(join(BASE_DIR, MEDIA_ROOT_DIR))
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

For, development purposes set :

```
DEBUG = True
```

And in urls.py add the following :

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Upload the image again and validate the Image, it should work now.